# Next-best-move engine

Tags: engines

Of course a real playing-the-next-best-move engine is silly,
it fouls up at the first trade. (Also, sometimes only one legal move
is possible.) Thus, my idea: It sets a cutoff instead and plays
the best moves with values < v. (This could also work for a neural net
engine, since it has a winning expectancy which could be used).

Has this been tried for fun? With different values of v? (This could be
interesting: at which v the position will get worse ultimately? -1 PU?)

[Comparable](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/34967/looking-for-a-chess-engine-that-instead-of-playing-the-best-move-randomly-choose) but not exactly the same.

Answer (score 1):

There's a "temperature" setting for Leela that does this. See [the description on the Lc0 website](https://lczero.org/dev/wiki/lc0-options/).

> Temperature: Tau value from softmax formula for the first move. If equal to 0, the engine picks the best move to make. Larger values increase randomness while making the move. Default value: 0.00 Minimum value: 0.00 Maximum value: 100.00

Comment: THX. So I recalled that correctly.